# Huawei E8372 AT command library

Tags: at-command, telecommunication, huawei-mobile-services

I have been searching for weeks and weeks to try find some form of online archive of AT command libraries for specific USB dongles/modems. I have a project and it requires a USB dongle to report on the mobile network signal quality. I have found a command (AT^HCSQ?) which seems to be Huawei specific and it is capable of returning a detailed signal quality report.

I am aware of the AT command (AT+CSQ) which is able to report on the received signal strength (RSSI) but that is not in enough detail for the project requirements.

I have found two Huawei dongles which have the required AT command in its library (E3276 and E5372) but I cannot source them in South Africa.

I have sourced the E8372 dongle and the only thing I require now is to determine if the device has the required AT command in its library (AT^HCSQ?).

I have contacted Huawei and all of my local network providers and none of them have been able to tell me a single thing with regards to the complete AT command library of the E8372 or even to confirm if the device has the command.

My question is then to anyone who has the Huawei E8372 dongle to please test the dongle using the " AT+CLAC " AT command, which returns the complete AT command library of the device, and to please help me determine if the E8372 has the " AT^HCSQ? " command.

Once can easily test the AT commands of the dongle on a Linux machine by installing Minicom and connecting the the device to the PC. Once a serial connecting has been established the command to determine the command list can be written to the dongle. Alternately the command can be tested by writing

> AT^HCSQ?

to the dongle using the serial connection and it should return either:

> ERROR

If the command is not in the library, or:

> ^HCSQ:"WCDMA",19,19,45

If the command is in the library.

I would really appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to determine if the E8372 dongle has the required command. Another device was purchased (E3372h-607) and was found to have to have the AT^HCSQ? command that I needed. It did require the HiLink mode to be changed by following this [link](http://blog.asiantuntijakaveri.fi/2015/07/convert-huawei-e3372h-153-from.html) with some modifications due to region.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid most AT commads are blocked. I tried to switch my stick into data-only mode however no success yet

```
ATI
Manufacturer: huawei
Model: E8372
Revision: 21.318.01.00.00
IMEI: 866457024091931
+GCAP: +CGSM,+DS,+ES

AT+CLAC
ERROR

AT^HCSQ?
ERROR
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I ended up purchasing the dongle and managed to get the device out of Hilink mode following this [link](http://blog.asiantuntijakaveri.fi/2015/07/convert-huawei-e3372h-153-from.html). Unfortunately the firmware in the link is for Asia devices (E3372h-153) where as I have a device from South Africa (E3372h-607) but I did manage to test and the device does have the command.

Comment: Sorry when i said purchased the dongle I mean i purchased the E3372 dongle which had the command I needed. I still am not sure of the E8372 model but the question has been answered for all intents and purposes.